# How to make a variable increase or decrease exponentially in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to increase or decrease a variable in a exponential or speeding up manner in a piece of code that happens every frame.

This code gets executed every frame:

```
  if (animationLenght > 1) {
    animationLenght --
    // implement speeding up value 
    ...       
  }
```

Doesn't have to be exponential exactly but like that it accelerates (or decelerates)

The animation variable decreases linearly by one on every frame.

I want to increase or decrease a value in an non linear fashion, but like speeding up or slowing down smothly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks up formulas for motion (speed, acceleration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Math.exp() function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/exp

```
let expNum;
for(let i=0; i < length; i++){
   expNum = Math.exp(i)
}
```